# Antlr @header declaration for C++ generation

Tags: antlr

In ANTLR version 2.X you could specify something was to go before or after the ANTLR includes via the code below.

```
header "pre_include_hpp" 
{
    #pragma warning( push )
    #pragma warning( disable : 4511 )   // couldn't generate copy constructor
}

header "post_include_hpp" 
{
    #pragma warning( pop )
}
```

With ANTLR v3.X it looks like this has been replaced by one @header block.

Is there a way to do what we previously did with ANTLR v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that I should be using

```
@lexer::preinclude
@lexer::postinclude
```

to replace the above definitions when I move from Antlr2 to Antlr3

see: http://www.antlr.org/api/C/atsections.html

for more details.